# Possible to develop apps for the newest (2012) iPod nano?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod

iPod nano with a larger screen and [other features](http://www.apple.com/ipod-nano/) is being released by Apple this month.

It *appears* to run iOS, so I'm curious whether it will be possible to develop apps for it, with Xcode or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No mention of App Store as a feature so I would say not likely.